# How to Add Zeros to Second Dimension of Array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, dimension

I have a latitude array with the shape (1111,) and am attempting to use matplotlib pcolormesh, but I'm getting an error since my array is not 2D so I am getting the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. Is there a way I can add 1111 zeros to the second dimension of my latitude array? Below is the code I have that is causing the error.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm

cmap = cm.get_cmap('BrBG')

cs = plt.pcolormesh(longitude.values, latitude.values, dens, cmap = cmap)

plt.title('Satellite Trajectory')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

plt.savefig('Satellite Trajectory', dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.025)

cb = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation = 'vertical')
cb.set_label(r'Density')
```

These are the first few lines of my Pandas latitude array:

```
0       50.224832
1       50.536422
2       50.847827
3       51.159044
4       51.470068
5       51.780895
6       52.091521
7       52.401941
8       52.712151
9       53.022145
10      53.331919
```

I have the same issue with the longitude array too. Here are some longitude values for reference.

```
0       108.873007
1       108.989510
2       109.107829
3       109.228010
4       109.350097
5       109.474136
6       109.600176
7       109.728265
8       109.858455
9       109.990798
10      110.125348
```

The other array shown is dens which is a density array and has the shape (5, 91, 181). Here are a few values for reference:

```
[6.042968853864891e-12, 6.042894605467602e-12, 6.042777396826408e-12, 6.042616263531836e-12, 6.042410211830538e-12, 6.042158216350682e-12, 6.0361190688090634e-12, 6.038107492458882e-12, 6.039984972063208e-12, 6.041748879958635e-12, 6.030375732644546e-12, 6.027898597657696e-12, 6.0251851962303345e-12, 6.0390021800772395e-12, 6.035096323493865e-12, 6.030879347062723e-12, 6.026343416350273e-12, 6.021480432118012e-12, 6.01628202402901e-12, 6.042274874237314e-12, 6.040409269411221e-1
```

I'm just stuck how to execute the pcolormesh without getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-685815191229> in <module>
      7 
      8 
----> 9 cs = plt.pcolormesh(longitude.values, latitude.values, dens, cmap = cmap)
     10 
     11 plt.title('Satellite Trajectory')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in pcolormesh(alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2771         *args, alpha=alpha, norm=norm, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin,
   2772         vmax=vmax, shading=shading, antialiased=antialiased,
-> 2773         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2774     sci(__ret)
   2775     return __ret

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in pcolormesh(self, alpha, norm, cmap, vmin, vmax, shading, antialiased, *args, **kwargs)
   5980         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   5981 
-> 5982         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   5983         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   5984         X = X.ravel()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in _pcolorargs(funcname, allmatch, *args)
   5547                 if isinstance(Y, np.ma.core.MaskedArray):
   5548                     Y = Y.data
-> 5549             numRows, numCols = C.shape
   5550         else:
   5551             raise TypeError(

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I'm assuming it is because of the longitde and latitude array shape, so I'm asking for help filling the second dimension so I have an array (1111,1111) rather than (1111,).

If you have another recommendation I would love help. I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop or a list comprehension in that case.

```
latitude = [50.224832, 50.536422, 50.847827, 51.159044, 51.470068]
longitude = [108.873007, 108.989510, 109.107829, 109.228010, 109.350097]
density = [.15,.25,.35,.45,.55]

output = [(latitude[i], longitude[i], density[i]) for i in range(len(latitude))]

print(output)

[(50.224832, 108.873007, 0.15), (50.536422, 108.98951, 0.25), (50.847827, 109.107829, 0.35), (51.159044, 109.22801, 0.45), (51.470068, 109.350097, 0.55)]
```

Comment: I want to plot longitude on the x-axis and latitude on the y-axis and have density show the colors for their values. So I would have three arrays for the plot, not just one.

Comment: Ah Ok. So to clarify. You are looking for an output like "(latitude, longitude, density)"? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes! So in pcolormesh I wanted longitude, latitude for the x and y axis and then dens for density to be displayed as colors. However, I don't think my latitude and longitude arrays are 2D so I'm getting an error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.